# Import Urho 3D Models

Tags: xamarin.forms, assimp, urhosharp

Recently i have to integrate into Xamarin.Forms a 3D Model view, i decided for Urho, but the issue is I havent found a simple tool that converts my .3ds or .fbx models, I tried with *AssImp* but always throws "**assimp export: no output format specified and I failed to guess it**", after i downloaded **3DGameStudio A7** and imported the models but URHO Says the format is not a model, there is a simple way to import the models without many steps?, what am i doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1):

You can use our command line tool to export it. Just open  a command-line prompt, navigate to your binary-folder containing assimp and use the following command:

```
assimp export box.3ds box.fbx
```

But you have to keep in mind, that the experimental fbx-export is currently only available on our current master. So you have to get the latest master from github and build the library from scratch.

Just follow our installation guide: [INSTALL GUIDE](https://github.com/assimp/assimp/blob/master/INSTALL)